# How to remove whitespace + hiphen + whitespace to only hiphen in url slug with preg_replace

Tags: preg-replace, slug, removing-whitespace

I am using this function. 
Everything works fine but When i enter item title like : "Example - A digital product" it shows me in url slug example---a-digital-product..Here after word example there are 3 hiphen continuous. Please help to resolve it.

```
public function item_slug($string){
        $slug=preg_replace(array('/[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+/','/[ -]+/'), array('',''),$string);
       return $slug;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to replace the second part by a single hyphen? https://3v4l.org/LGAs3

Comment: yes.. here after example there is space+hiphen+space.  so in slug it is giving ---.

Comment: If you test the example in the link, you don't get `---` Did you test it using that code?

Comment: Yes i have tested with link that's why asked here.

Comment: Can you share a link like https://3v4l.org/LGAs3 with the undesired outcome?

Comment: Hey brother, Thank you very very much! It is solved. I have used code what you have written in the link. You are great. I am really happy. Good experience on stackoverflow.

Comment: Good to hear that you have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hyphen in the second replacement to replace 1 or more occurrences of a space or hyphen you match with `[ -]+`  with a single hyphen.

Example code:

```
function item_slug($string){
    return preg_replace(array('/[^A-Za-z0-9 -]+/','/[ -]+/'), array('','-'),$string);
}

$strings = [
    "example---a-digital-product..",
    "Example - A digital product"
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    echo item_slug($str) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
example-a-digital-product
Example-A-digital-product
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/LGAs3)

Comment: here if i want to convert all capital character in small letter then what is required?